# Listing available hashes in GNUPG2?

Tags: gnupg

I want to use the **setpref** command (under `--edit-key` ) to set a key's prefered hash-algorithms in `gnupg2`, and was wondering if there is a way to list which hashes my version of gpg supports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The supported hashes can be obtained by running the command with the `--version` flag.

From the GnuPG [setpref documentation](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/OpenPGP-Key-Management.html#OpenPGP-Key-Management) (bold emphasis mine):

```
setpref string

    Set the list of user ID preferences to string for all (or just the
    selected) user IDs. Calling setpref with no arguments sets the preference
    list to the default (either built-in or set via --default-preference-
    list), and calling setpref with "none" as the argument sets an empty
    preference list. Use gpg --version to get a list of available algorithms.
```